# How do I calculate an effect size (cohens d) from a % difference between interventions and control

Tags: effect-size, cohens-d

If I am basing results on a previous study which has a difference between intervention groups (5 intervention groups) and 1 control of 10.9%.

How do I calculate the effect size (d)?

I want to be able to detect this difference in a new study with 80% power and 5% significance level.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the proportion for each condition, not simply the difference between them as power is affected by how close to 0 or 1 the proportions are. Also, Cohen's $d$ is not well suited to power analysis of binary outcomes for this very reason, although there are methods for estimating $d$ from such data (e.g., by converting a logged odds ratio). For purposes of power analysis, Cohen's $h$ is well suited to this situation.